# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7d400300 in tid 27503 when adding mircroblink license file

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, microblink

So I have a project that contain a microblink library which is I need to declare it in MainActivity, here what it looks like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    /** Set the License from the file*/
    MicroblinkSDK.setLicenseFile("this is my license file", this);

    

}
```

Then I run the program and getting error fatal signal, but when the declaration code from microblink I remove it can work as usual. I've tried search for the solution and there it said to adding this

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

in the manifest file but failed and the error doesn't change. Some help would be so nice!

here is the debug log

```
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=26KB, data=29KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=29KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/art: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=53KB
After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=53KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/line:110: --- Implementation #2 with key 0x52
D/line:37: Unlocking BlinkID native library version 4.7.0
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7d400300 in tid 25983 (ana.wandaflpdev)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:50648', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, from the log, I can see that you are using version 4.7, which is an old version of BlinkID which came out in February 2019.
I suggest trying to implement the latest version (5.9), which you can download here:
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android/releases/tag/v5.9.0

Also, regarding the license key method, the recommendation is to implement it in the way that you extend the `Android Application class` and set the license in the `onCreate callback` like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MicroblinkSDK.setLicenseFile("path/to/license/file/within/assets/dir", this);
    }
}
```

More details here:
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android#performing-your-first-scan

Comment: when i change it to 5.9 the error change to error merge manifest appCompatFactory, i think i need to migrate my android support library to androidx..

Comment: Yes, you will need to migrate to AndroidX since the BlinkID in version 5 migrated to AndroidX dependencies as well.

Comment: i've done migrating but i got a new error :app:kaptDebugKotlin do you know how to solve it ?@Milan